# Can removing a contraceptive implant cause secondary amenorrhea?

Tags: side-effects, endocrinology, contraception, menstruation, uterus

When a woman stops taking birth control medication, she might suffer from various side effects. Can secondary amenorrhea (i.e. missing periods for more than 3 months) be induced by the removal of a contraceptive implant?